# Dynamic ActiveX.ComboBox Change Event

Tags: excel, vba, events, combobox, activex

i got a Problem while working on a little project. I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

**What i am trying to accomplish?**

I create dynamic new ActiveX.ComboBoxes with a given List in it. When the user selects the ComboBox and changes the selected Item in the List i need an event to trigger.
For every dynamic comboboxes the event should be the same.
Example: Combobox in D10 changes from "ItemA" to "ItemB" then i need an Event that checks in a Table for "ItemB" (Column A) and then pick the Value of the same Row of Column B and put it in the Column E10 where the combobox is located.

I have no clue how to add DynamicEvents and then let them act all the same. And even if i still need to delete events dynamic too since the user can delete Rows and Comboboxes again.

**What i tried:**

Linking the Combobox to its Cell below it and then i tried to get the "worksheet Change" Event working, but apparently it doesnt work with linkedcells....

**Current Code:**

```
 Sub NewComboBox(ByVal Row As Integer, Name As String, CellWidth As Integer,  CellHeight As Integer)

    Set ourCombo = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                Link:=True, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=plan.Cells(Row, CellNumber_Product).Left, Top:=plan.Cells(Row, CellNumber_Product).Top, Width:=CellWidth, _
                Height:=CellHeight)
        With ourCombo
            .LinkedCell = plan.Cells(Row, CellNumber_Product).Address          
            .ListFillRange = "DTB_1!A:A"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    CB1=ComboBox1.Value
    R=WorksheetFunction.Match(CB1, Columns("A:A"),0)

    Activesheet.OLEObjects("ComBox2").ListFillRange =Cells(R,2).Address

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your time and effort. Can you explain this? I dont fully understand how it should work.
What is   "Combobox1.value" and  whatdoes the  WorksheetFunction.Match do? and how does it work?
same for the last line?

Comment: Combobox1.value mean your selected "Item B".

Comment: Worksheetfunction.match same as match function use at Excel to check selected "Item B" row.

Comment: Thanks! i understood. But one last question, how do i "activate" the Event for every Combobox? The Code in my Posts shows how i add currently the new comboboxen, how do i create an event / link them to "ComboBox1_Change" so it activates? Thank you, i really appreciate it

Comment: Right click the combobox and click view code, then you will go to the event of the combobox.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is i am creating multiple comboboxes during runtime (dynamic) and every new combobox needs the event. So i cant do that i need to add the event programmatically somehow